# YouTube iframe embed code in IE7/8 throws JS error using controls parameter

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, youtube, embed

Getting JS error when using one of the parameters outlined by YouTube developer documentation - "controls".  [link to doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls)  This parameter doesn't load the player initially to increase page load performance.

If I use this code...

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0VikYBOXRkg?controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I receive an error in IE7 and IE8:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.
>
> www-embed-cued-vflvSROs4.js

Made a fiddle to illustrate issue if you view in IE7 or 8. Other browsers work fine. - http://jsfiddle.net/aBK6V/

Any ideas? I can't find a single related bug anywhere.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. Keep in mind that opening http://www.youtube.com/embed/0VikYBOXRkg directly on IE browser is also not working. THis is probably because IE7 is not officially supported by the Youtube team anymore, but I wish there's still a better fallback...

Comment: Please see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3985